# How can I return a query parameter using regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

How can I use regex and the replace function to retrieve:

```
"?topic=MyCategory"
```

From these strings:

```
"?topic=marketing&page=1"
"?topic=Sales&page=2"
"?topic=Recruiting"
"?page=2&topic=recruiting"
```

But retrieves null or an empty string from these:

```
"?page=4"
"" (empty string)
```

I've been able to get to:
\?topic=(.*?)&  and replace with $1.

And hope it's ok to ask as a follow up question, where can I find a good regex guide/cheatsheet.

Comment: You should replace `(.*?)&` with `[^&]*` or `[^&]+`. And use `String#match` or `RegExp#exec` to extract the substring. [Here is an awesome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean) regex knowledge source.

Comment: I think you should use: [^&"]+ to get category when there's one or two pairs.